# asp.net Membership tables in sql azure. PK by default nonclustered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure-sql-database

SQL Azure only supports clustered Primary keys.
The SQL membership provider for asp.net creates its tables with nonclustered primary keys, because they are GUIDs (the reason for that is beyond the scope of this question).

What is the quickest and easiest way to make those standard Membership tables compatible with SQL Azure? Or does SQL Azure not support GUID PK's?

This is for an already created MVC3 project that we would like to migrate to Azure.

**UPDATE**

SQL Azure does actually support nonclustered PK's, but it requires at least one Clustered Index. If you are using SSMS locally to manage your azure DB, be sure to update to the latest version or you'll get some confusing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this. The easiest way is to use aspnet_regsqlazure. Here are some links:

http://tofutim.wordpress.com/
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2006191/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3539

**Update**

A quick glance at our sql azure membership db shows that the uniqueidentifier pk's are indeed nonclustered:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Applications](
    [ApplicationName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LoweredApplicationName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [ApplicationId] ASC
    ),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [LoweredApplicationName] ASC
    ),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [ApplicationName] ASC
    )
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Applications] ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ApplicationId]
GO
```

Comment: ahh nice, I didn't know there was a specific command to generate sql azure membership tables.

Comment: SQL Azure now supports heaps on V12 servers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188029.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396